# Differentiate between different forms using cgi python

Tags: python, html, cgi

I have multiple forms in a html file, which all call the same python cgi script.  For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="script.cgi" enctype="multipart/data-form">
....
</form>
...
<form method="POST" name="form2" action="script.cgi" enctype="multipart/data-form">
...
</form>
...
</body>
</html>
```

And in my cgi script I do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import cgi

print "content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n"
form = cgi.FieldStorate();
...
```

I am unable to get the data from the second from.  I have tried to call FieldStorage multiple times, but that did not seem to work.  So my question is how do I access different forms in the same cgi script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. The browser submits one form, or the other, but not both.

If you need data from both forms, merge the forms into one `<form>` tag instead.

Answer (score 1):

First, `FieldStorage()` consumes standard input, so it should only be instantiated once.

Second, only the data in the submitted form is sent to the server. The other forms may 
as well not exist.

So while you can use the same cgi script to process both forms, if you need process both forms at the same time, as Martijn suggested, merge the forms into one `<form>`.